# Getting cassandra connection error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cassandra

I am unable to connect to Cassandra (ver2.0.5) using Eclipse. Here is the complete log from the error:

> 16:06:59.818 [main] WARN  c.d.driver.core.FrameCompressor - Cannot
> find Snappy class, you should make sure the Snappy library is in the
> classpath if you intend to use it. Snappy compression will not be
> available for the protocol.
>
> [...] omitted for brevity

Comment: Unsupported protocol version suggests that your client driver version is incompatible with the server version. What version of the driver and the server are you using?

Comment: The error message thrown is not always the root cause. I have seen this occur when the real issue is JAR files missing from the classpath.

Comment: This is not necessarily a fatal error, unless you actually enable Snappy compression. See my reply on this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29947679/3775443

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use maven to import snappy/lz4 or whatever other compression your using.

[LZ4](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.jpountz.lz4/lz4)

[Snappy](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial.snappy/snappy-java)

Comment: Note, that you need to include both of them Snappy and LZ4

Answer (score 2):

I just hit the same problems, seems due to some update of the libs. Here is my solution, by adding these dependencies in the POM.xml.

groupid/ artifactId/version:

- com.datastax.cassandra cassandra-driver-core 2.1.0
- com.google.guava guava 16.0.1 io.netty netty 3.9.0.Final
- com.codahale.metrics metrics-core 3.0.2
- org.slf4j slf4j-api 1.7.5
- org.slf4j slf4j-simple 1.6.1
- net.jpountz.lz4 lz4 1.2.0
- org.xerial.snappy snappy-java 1.1.1.3

The last 3 are not mentioned in the Datastax user manual but reminded in the compiling process. Just try!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing files from your class path. Depending on which driver you are using, you need to ensure you are including *all* dependent JAR files.

Tthe Datastax 2.0 driver has less dependencies, the 1.x series has more. 1.x depends on basically all the cassandra jar files.